# Rails: Strategy for keeping track of highest score per level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, data-integrity, after-save

I'm working on a Rails app that needs to keep track of a user's **highest score** for each **level** that they play.

Each **attempt** on a level has multiple **rounds**, the sum of scores for each round in the attempt is cached as total_score in the attempt.

Models:

- High Score (belongs_to: user, level, attempt)
- Level (has_many: attempts)
- Attempt (has_many: rounds, belongs_to: user, level)
- Round (belongs_to: attempt)
- User (has_many: high_scores, attempts)

When a round is saved in updates the total_score for the attempt that it belongs to. I'm currently using the following naive implementation, but plan to refactor soon. Before I refactor I'd like to know if there are any better strategies for keeping this information up to date.

```
def update_high_score_if_needed
  high_score = HighScore.where(user_id: self.user_id, level_id: self.level_id).first
  if high_score.nil?
    high_score = HighScore.create(attempt_id: self.id, level_id: self.level_id, user_id: self.user_id, score: self.total_score)
  else
    if high_score.score < self.total_score
      high_score.update_attributes(attempt: self, score: self.total_score)
      self.update_attribute(:was_high_score, true)
    else
      record_attempt = self.user.attempts.where(level_id: self.level_id).order('total_score DESC').first
      if record_attempt.nil?
        high_score.destroy
      else
        high_score.update_attributes(attempt: record_attempt, score: record_attempt.total_score)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I know that I could just query for this information, but I'd like a fast response when I want to display all high scores and I'd like to be able to store if each attempt was a high score at the time that it was completed.

Comment: I would seriously consider using stored procedures and triggers at the RDBMS level for something like this and maybe even a virtual table but I have not used Rails models with virtual tables before, which is strange because I've used them plenty of times in multi tier corporate desktop apps, so I'm not sure if Rails will play nicely here. Anyway, for the amount of data calculations that are likely to happen letting the database take the load would be my best advice

Comment: Out of curiosity with a bit of research plus a little test app I just knocked up shows that mySql views work really well with rails and performance improvement seems to be worth the effort but tests would need to be done to proved scaleability in a production environment and checked against whatever RDBMS you use, I know it's not what you asked about but definitely worth the mind shift I think

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to give it a try for my app… I worry that it moves some of the logic out of Rails, but that's probably going to happen anyways as the App grows (and I think the change would be frozen in a migration anyways).